# LaTeX citation undefined

Tags: latex, bibtex, citations, overleaf

I am trying to add a citation to my paper but keep getting the same error:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `Gorantla2023DynaQ' on page 6 undefined on input line 143.

In the .tex file it is represented as follows:
"The code implemented was inspired by **?**."

I used the following to create a new citation in the .bib file:

```
@misc{Gorantla2023DynaQ,
  author = {Ashok Gorantla},
  title = {Extending Q-Learning With Dyna-Q for Enhanced Decision-Making},
  year = {2023},
  howpublished = {\url{https://dzone.com/articles/extending-q-learning-with-dyna-q#:~:text=Update%20Rule%20%2D%20Q%2Dvalues%20are,the%20importance%20of%20future%20rewards}},
  publisher = {Dzone}
}
```

I am new to LaTeX so I only have tried to change the @misc, but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709288/36296

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can see if there are any errors in the code. Please also include how you compile your document so we can check if you run the necessary bibtex.